# Unable to configure SB to use MySQL hosted BATCH_* tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-batch

I am having some trouble configuring Spring to use BATCH_* tables hosted by MySQL.
I created the tables ok according to docs however it looks like the code is trying to get a sequence number using the Oracle flavour function.

The error I get is:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'BATCH_JOB_SEQ' in field list

But this is hiding the real problem. I debugged it and its trying to run this code:

```
select " + getIncrementerName() + ".nextval from dual";
```

Which is obviously Oracle dialect. I notice that there exists the correct incrementer in my environment here:
org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer()

but its calling
org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.OracleMaxValueIncrementer()

I have setup my data source thus:

```
 <bean id="springDataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
          <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
          <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://10.252.205.5:3306/MASKNG" />
          <property name="username" value="MASKNG" />
          <property name="password" value="maskng" />
      </bean>
```

Anyone have an ideas as this is a show stopper for us atm

Comment: can you please print this line with `System.out.print(select " + getIncrementerName() + ".nextval from dual";);` and show us the result?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you created the BATCH_* tables according to the MySQL documentation here? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql  That clearly shows the BATCH_JOB_SEQ table as one of the tables, and there's an insert into it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, well, I really should RTM a little more...you just have to tell the jobRepository bean what type of DB you are using

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="springDataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="validateTransactionState" value="${jobRepository.validationTransactionState:true}" />
    <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="${jobRepository.isolationLevelForCreate}" />
    <!-- <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" /> -->
    <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="BATCH_" />
    <property name="lobHandler" ref="lobHandler"/>
</bean>
```